# I am trying to use promise ina function to receive data and put them in array and then return the array

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

My function uses promises, but it is not working correctly:

```
getShirtcolorsCount(){
    var params_red ;
    var red ;
    var params_blue ;
    var blue ;
    var numb = 0 ;
    var docClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    // Query voor Shirts 
    params_red = {
        TableName: 'ShirtApp',
        IndexName: 'Shirt-index',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'ShirtC = :sbs AND ShirtQuantity >  :snr ' ,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':sbs': 'Red' ,
            ':snr' : numb
        }
    };

    var redPromise = docClient.query(params_red).promise();
    redPromise.then(function(data){
        console.log('Success');  
        red = data.Count;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    params_blue = {
        TableName: 'ShirtApp',
        IndexName: 'Shirt-index',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'ShirtC = :sbs AND ShirtQuantity >  :snr ' ,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':sbs': 'Blue' ,
            ':snr' : numb
        }
    };

    var bluePromise = docClient.query(params_blue).promise();
    bluePromise.then(function(data){
        console.log('Success');  
        blue = data.Count ;      //NEED THAT to add to the array
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    var ShirtInfo = [{
        name: 'RedColor',
        value: red
    }, {
        name: 'BlueColor',
        value: blue
    }];

    // **** HERE I NEED HELP what should I PUT in the Promise.all for the array
    // I want redPromise and bluePromise to run at the same time after I receive 
    // data then add then to the array and return the array as the function
    Promise.all([redPromise, bluePromise]).then([ShirtInfo])

    return ShirtInfo;
}
```

As I added in comments, I want to run `redPromise` and `BluePromise` at the same time and after they received data from the web, add them to the array. And after that return that array. Almost everything works only the part where `Promise.all` is used. I can't figure out what to put after `.then` so the values would be added to the array:

```
Promise.all([redPromise, bluePromise]).then([])
```

And I can't figure out what to put to return the array using promise.

Comment: Do you need to access `resolve` values from `redPromise` and `bluePromise` in `Promise.all#then`?

Comment: Very bad formatted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- You need to *return* the value of `red` and `blue` inside the `then` callback, otherwise those promises will resolve to `undefined`.
- Likewise, you need to return the return value of `Promise.all`
- You cannot acccess `red` and `blue` synchronously, as those will still be undefined. So that must happen within a `then` callback.

I would also avoid the code duplication you have, and work with a list of colors you are interested in, and then cycle through those:

```
getShirtcolorsCount(){
    var params;
    var colors;
    var promises;
    var numb = 0;
    var docClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    colors = ['Red', 'Blue']; // <--- make code generic
    promises = colors.map(function (color) {
        // Query voor Shirts 
        var param = {
            TableName: 'ShirtApp',
            IndexName: 'Shirt-index',
            KeyConditionExpression: 'ShirtC = :sbs AND ShirtQuantity > :snr ',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':sbs': color, // <-- make it dynamic to avoid code duplication
                ':snr' : numb
            }
        };
        return docClient.query(params_red).promise();
    });

    // Make sure to return the promise    
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function (responses) {
        console.log('Success');  
        var shirtInfo = responses.map(function (data, i) {
            return {
                name: color[i] + 'Color',
                value: data.Count
            };
        });
        return shirtInfo;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Once you work with promises, you must use the results as promises too. You cannot expect a function to return the value synchronously. So when you call `getShirtcolorsCount`, use `then` to access the result:

```
getShirtcolorsCount().then(function (shirtInfo) {
    console.log(shirtInfo);
});
```

Comment: I got error on this part of the code   value: data.Count  the the erorr is [ts] Property 'Count' does not exist on type '{}'. any.                                       If I remove the .Count it works but I dont need all the whole object only the Count property

Comment: I got error but fixed it  return Promise.all(promises).then(function (responses) { }     need to be ---> (responses: any)

Comment: OK, that was a TypeScript error. My answer is in plain JavaScript. But indeed with `: any` you circumvent that TypeScript complains.

Comment: since I am using it in angular I needed to add the return of shirtInfo to a var tingle in a component so I did this and it worked             this.ddb.getShirtcolorsCount().then(shirtInfo => this.tingle = shirtInfo);  I   thx again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I your case results from `redPromise` and `bluePromise` are written in function scope variable and can be pushed to array like this:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  Promise.all([redPromise, bluePromise]).then(function () {
    ShirtInfo.push(red)
    ShirtInfo.push(blue)
    resolve(ShirtInfo)
  })
}
```

And where you call function that fetches this array you should also use

```
getShirtColorsCount().then(function(shirtInfo) {
  // Stuff
})
```

p.s. It will callback hell. May be better use `babel` and `async-await` or generator functions? It will be more readable

Comment: You should not provide code that uses the [Promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: @trincot i didn't know. I used this always

Comment: @trincot also eslint:standard not mark that as antipattern